# How to cache data received from an Ajax call?

Tags: jquery, ajax, caching

I would like to cache data received from the server so that there are a minimum number of PHP/MySQL instructions executed.  I know that the cache option is automatically set for $.ajax().  However, I am seeing MySQL instructions every time $.ajax() is called even if postdata is the same as it was in a previous call.  Am I missing something?  What is the best way to cache data received from the server?  Here is my code:

```
var postdata = {'pid':'<?php echo $project_id;?>',
                'record_id':this.id};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "get_note.php",
    data: postdata
}).done(function(data){
    if (data != '0') {
        // Add dialog content
        $('#note_container').html(data);
        $('#note_container').dialog();
    } else {
        alert(woops);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the idea. Tweak it to your needs, of course.

```
function getAjaxData(){
    var $node = $('#note_container');
    if ($node.data('ajax-cache').length == 0) {
        $.ajax({
            // do stuff. 
            success: function(data){
                // Add dialog content
                $node.html(data).data('ajax-cache',data).dialog();
            }
        });
    } else {
        $node.html( $node.data('ajax-cache') ).dialog();
    }
}
getAjaxData();
```

Comment: The browser handles caching itself if you let it. If it tries to make the EXACT same request twice, it just uses it's own cache. Why re-invent the wheel when the browser handles caching for you?

Comment: Not sure, seems like a good concept to me. By storing it on the element, it get's automatically cleaned when the element is removed by jQuery.

Comment: @Adam Caching of ajax requests can be inconsistent (as Civil777 is seeing), one way to make it consistent is to handle it yourself.

Answer (score 4):

I would handle the cache myself:

```
// declare this on global scope
var ajaxCache = {};
...

if (!ajaxCache[this.id]) {
    ajaxCache[this.id] = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "get_note.php",
        data: {'pid':'<?php echo $project_id;?>','record_id':this.id}
    });
}

ajaxCache[this.id].done(function(){
    if (data != '0') {
        // Add dialog content
        $('#note_container').html(data);
        $('#note_container').dialog();
    } else {
        alert('woops');
    }
});
```

This way, if a request with said id has already happened, a new request will not be made unless you remove it from the cache.

Comment: but will the deferred.done() method be called again when returning cached data?

Comment: called, no, but you can attach more callbacks to it and the callbacks will fire immediately because it is already resolved.

Comment: Looks like your `data` variable is undefined in `.done() ` callback

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a cache parameter like:

```
$.ajax({
...
...
cache : true
});
```

Comment: The cache parameter is true by default.  Just to be sure, I set it as you suggested.  I am still seeing MySQL instructions being processed by the server.