# Return custom fields with ajax when hover a link wordpress

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, wordpress

I have javascript on custom page for get custom fields when hover a link of title post. my [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17982453/1297435)

**custom.php**

```
// other stuff here, wp_query etc

<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></a>
```

**footer.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

var request;
$('a[rel="bookmark"]')
  .mouseenter(function() {
    var dataId = $(this).attr('data-id');
    request = $.ajax({
      dataType: "JSON",
      url: '<?php echo admin_url("admin-ajax.php"); ?>',
      data: {"action": "our_ajax_function", "id": dataId},
      success: function(data){
        if(!data) {
            console.log('data empty');
        } else if(data.error) {
            console.log('error');
        } else {
            console.log(data);
        }
      },
      complete: function(){
        console.log('complete')
      }
  })


  })
  .mouseleave(function() {
     if (request) {
        request.abort();
        request = null;
     }
  });
});

</script>
```

And this my custom function on **function.php** to `get_post_meta` by `id` of post.

```
function our_ajax_function(){

    $output = get_customs($_REQUEST['id']);
    if( is_array( $output ) ) {
        $output = json_encode( $output );
    }
    else {
        wp_send_json_error(); 
    }
}


function get_customs($id){
    $custom = array(
        "image" => get_post_meta($post->$id, 'image', true),
        "synopsis" => get_post_meta($post->$id, 'synopsis', true)
    );
    if( count($custom) ) {
        return $custom;
    }
    return false;
}

add_action('wp_ajax_our_ajax_function', 'our_ajax_function');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_our_ajax_function', 'our_ajax_function');
```

So, I want the output should be `$image`, `$synopsis` using `$id` form attribute `data-id` of `a[rel="bookmark"]`when mouse enter it and the request triggers. But on console I get `data empty`. I'm sure, `$output` are not empty.

```
XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=our_ajax_function&id=17710".
data empty 
complete
```

Sorry, I'm not telling you to correct my code. I just want to know the right way to do get custom fields, anyone can help me?

Comment: Just skimmed through it: are you sure you want to make an ajax call every time an item is hovered? Is it really worth saving a few kilobytes of memory for making constant server calls?

Comment: @Shomz I have read this [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10399866/1297435) , I think [this good concept best way to received cache data from server](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10399962/1297435) instead I get data using ajax from page. And I will remove `request(abort)` or using timeoute/delay for `.mouseenter` something link hovered link of name on facebook :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in `get_customs()` when you use `$post->$id` instead of just `$id`. For example if the `$id` was `123` then you would be using the `$post->123` property instead of the proper ID passed into the function.

```
$custom = array(
    "image" => get_post_meta( $id, 'image', true ),
    "synopsis" => get_post_meta( $id, 'synopsis', true )
);
```

Comment: I have resolved, found this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6110690/1297435, thanks @doublesharp